# Grouping Json response with keys in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am new to java development. I am learning json parsing. I got json response something like this.

```
    "sizePrices": [
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 0.00,
            "sizeCode": "S",
            "sizeNumber": 100
        },
        {
            "cargoHandoverPrice": 1.66,
            "sizeCode": "M",
            "sizeNumber": 110

        },   
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 0.00,
            "sizeCode": "L",
            "sizeNumber": 120

        }
        ,   
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 0.00,
            "sizeCode": "XL",
            "sizeNumber": 130

        },   
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 0.00,
            "sizeCode": "XXL",
            "sizeNumber": 140

        },   
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 1.66,
            "sizeCode": "XXXL",
            "sizeNumber": 150

        }
    ]
```

if price match it should give me sizerange back
like below

I want to parse this Json into something like this.

```
    [
        {

            "cargoHandoverPrice": 0.00,
            "SizeRange": "S-XXL",

        },
        {
            "cargoHandoverPrice": 1.66,
            "SizeRange": "M-XXXL",


        }
    ]
```

How can I achieve this? My motive is to group all the sizeranges according to their prices.

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking 2 questions here:
 1. how do I parse the JSON into Java objects and, later, convert back to JSON
 2. once I have the data in Java objects, how do I group by price

On question 1, there are several good quality JSON parsers available, such as https://github.com/google/gson It is fairly straightforward to parse the JSON and construct the appropriate objects. But if you read the tutorials, try to use the parser and then have problems, come back to SO and ask a specific question.

On question 2, here is a suggestion:

```
enum Size { S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXL }

class SizePrice {
    private final double price;
    private final Size size;
    private final int number;
}

List<SizePrice> sizePrices = <read from JSON>

Map<Double,List<SizePrice>> sizePricesGroupedByPrice = sizePrices.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(sp -> sp.price));
```

The `Size` enum is deliberately in a size order so you can get the smallest and largest (by ordinal()) size is generating the range.

Comment: but i need to use Jackson for parsing these JSON, can i have a sample code where i can use jackson for parsing my json and get the o/p

Comment: yes that's fine, but any link to get the reference at least as I have never used.

Comment: You can try below snippet to parse - 

`List<Item> items = objectMapper.convertValue(objectMapper.readTree(json).get("sizePrices"), new TypeReference<List<Item>>(){});`

Where Item is SizePrice mentioned by @sprinter

Comment: Thanks a lot while executing i am getting below exception.                                                                                                            
  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.<clinit>                                                                    I have added dependency like this **<dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> <version>2.8.0</version> </dependency>**

Comment: Hi @sprinter,i have added below code to get the list of sizeprices and i am getting the values.` List<SizePrices> items = mapper.convertValue(mapper.readTree(json).get("sizePrices"), new TypeReference<List<SizePrices>>() {
            });`  and i can able to group by also.now i am getting list of size 2, hereafter how can i get those ranges?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON library such as *Josson* to do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"sizePrices\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 0.0," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"S\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 100" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 1.66," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"M\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 110" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 0.0," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"L\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 120" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 0.0," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"XL\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 130" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 0.0," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"XXL\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 140" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"cargoHandoverPrice\": 1.66," +
    "            \"sizeCode\": \"XXXL\"," +
    "            \"sizeNumber\": 150" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "sizePrices" +
    ".group(cargoHandoverPrice)" +
    ".field(SizeRange: concat(elements.findByMin(sizeNumber).sizeCode," +
    "                         '-'," +
    "                         elements.findByMax(sizeNumber).sizeCode)," +
    "       elements:)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ {
  "cargoHandoverPrice" : 0.0,
  "SizeRange" : "S-XXL"
}, {
  "cargoHandoverPrice" : 1.66,
  "SizeRange" : "M-XXXL"
} ]
```